# User input don't get validated when user navigate between pages

Tags: forms, jsf, navigation, submit

My Problem is, that when the user navigates between pages, the userinput don't get submitted and validated.

At the time I'm learning JSF an writing an Application. The Application consists of various pages. I use an default template in wich I insert the navigation template.

Here is my navigation template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">


<ui:insert name="navigation">
            <nav>           
                <h:panelGroup>
                <h:form>
                <h:commandButton value="GO BACK" styleClass="button" action="GOBACK"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Reset" pt:type="Reset" styleClass="button" action="RESET"/>
                <h:commandButton value="GO FORWARD" action="GOFORWARD" styleClass="button"/>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
            </nav>
    </ui:insert>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is my default.xhtml template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
  <title><ui:insert name="title">Page</ui:insert></title>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="normalize.css"/>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="atmosphere.css"/>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="layout.css"/>


</h:head>

<h:body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
</div>


<div id="content">
  <ui:insert name="content">
        Content area.  See comments below this line in the source.
  </ui:insert>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ui:insert name="navigation">
        <ui:include src="navigation.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </ui:insert>
</div>
</div>
</h:body>

</html>
```

In the faces-config I have some navigations rules, for example:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>firstPage.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/firstPage.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>GOFORWARD</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/secondPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Now I want to make an content-template-client, with a `<h:form>` in it. But the Problem is now, that when the User push one of the Navigation-Buttons the User Input don't get validated and submitted (because the navigation is in a other form). Do you know a solution? (Or do I go the wrong way with the navigation in an extra template?)

My only idea is to write a `<h:form>` around the content and navigation part in the default.xhtml template.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't technically related to what your problem is, but you really shouldn't be using your `faces-config` file to define navigation cases, those should be defined in your individual files or even in your backing bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with RevanProdigalKnight. For instance, except navigating by faces-config. You can navigate by putting in the backing bean like the following code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class Bean{

public String goToNextPage(){
return "nextPage.xhtml";
}
```

If you want to send information to the next page

```
   public String goToNextPage(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap()
            .put("info", yourInformation);
     return "nextPage.xhtml"
```

Then in the xhtml, you will have

```
     h:commandButton value="GO FORWARD" action = "#{bean.goToNextPage()}"
```

Now as for submission and validation, in the backing bean you will get the information that was inputted in the field and do your validation, there is many ways to do validations. Assuming you have a text field name userField in the first page and that one of the requirements is for the user to input something, then

First Page.xhtml

```
   h:inputText value = "#{bean.userField}" required = "true"  requiredMessage = "Input something please"
```

Then in the bean
  Make a field called userField

```
  private String userField = "";
```

Then make getters and setters for it